# Is there a way to pass model attribute into another attribute?

Tags: django

I'm using {% autoescape off %} to render html that I add through admin page. I want to get another variable of the model.

```
post.html

{% autoescape off %}
    {{ post.content }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Is it possible to pass another attribute of the same model into post.content? Something like that

```
post.content

<img src="{{ post.main_image.url }}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've finally made it. My goal was to create CMS-ish admin page of a model, where I could add raw html, django tags and variables directly to the content attribute along with other attributes like titles, categories, images and so on. I've managed to do it by using and customizing django-dbtemplates package.

```
pip install django-dbtemplates
```

First, fork template model from dbtemplates and add your model as a foreign key

```
blog/models.py

from dbtemplates.models import Template as CoreTemplate

class Template(CoreTemplate):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then just customize your admin.py to show template field as an attribute

```
blog/admin.py

from .models import Post, Template

class TemplateInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Template
    extra = 0

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TemplateInline, ]
```

**Optional**

You can generate html names of you template based on your model slug by modifying save function of the Template class

```
blog/models.py

from dbtemplates.models import Template as CoreTemplate
from dbtemplates.conf import settings

class Template(CoreTemplate):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.last_changed = now()
        slug = self.post.slug
        self.name = f'{slug}-content.html'
        if settings.DBTEMPLATES_AUTO_POPULATE_CONTENT and not self.content:
            self.populate()
        super(Template, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then in your html you can render this template with context manager

```
post.html

{% with post.slug|add:'-content.html' as content %}
    {% include content %}
{% endwith %}
```

Now in your admin settings you can have just one big content field from basic Template class

```
blog/admin.py

from .models import Template
from django.forms import Textarea


class TemplateInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Template
    extra = 0
    fields = ('content',)
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows': 40, 'cols': 150})},
    }
```

To remove default dbtemplates Template class from your admin panel just unregister it in your admin settings

```
blog/admin.py

from dbtemplates.admin import Template as CoreTemplate

admin.site.unregister(CoreTemplate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup. Assuming there is a post, and it has a main_image, which has a url, there shouldn't be any problem. You may want to check in the template if you are not sure yourself first though. So to be safer, you should do:

```
{% if post and post.main_image %}
<img src="{{ post.main_image.url }}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It never hurts to add it to the template and see if it renders anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already tried this but unfortunately it doesn't work. My page renders this: <img src="{{ post.main_image.url }}">.

Comment: No problem. In that case, it looks like django might not be rendering the template at all or you have some syntax issues somewhere. Could you show the entire template and the code where you render it?

Comment: The template renders, that's the variable inside post.content that doesn't render. For example, I get the image in this case 
{% for post in posts %}
<img src="{{ post.main_image.url }}">
    {% autoescape off %}
        {{ post.content }}
    {% endautoescape %}
{% endfor %}

post.content is a TextField and it renders all html tags I pass into it but not images:

<div class="row article-row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <img src="{{ post.main_image.url }}">
    </div>
</div>

It doesn't work with static tags either.